# Как заставить грид-элемент тянуться по собственному контенту?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, css-grid

Вот такая несложная раскладка на гридах: https://jsfiddle.net/xwu2gqLj/35/

```css
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 3fr;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "left main" "right main" "footer footer"
}

.header {
  background: gold;
  grid-area: header;
}

.left {
  background: silver;
  grid-area: left;
}

.main {
  background: blue;
  grid-area: main;
}

.right {
  background: green;
  grid-area: right;
}

.footer {
  background: red;
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <aside class="left">Вот этот грид-элемент должен тянуться (в высоту) по контенту, а не по высоте .main ... </aside>
  <main class="main">Товарищи! дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации дальнейших направлений развития. Таким образом реализация намеченных плановых заданий представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки модели
    развития. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также рамки и место обучения кадров способствует подготовки и реализации дальнейших направлений развития. Товарищи! укрепление и развитие структуры обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие
    в формировании систем массового участия. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что рамки и место обучения кадров обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании существенных финансовых и административных условий. Не следует,
    однако забывать, что постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки форм развития. Повседневная практика показывает, что консультация с широким активом требуют определения и уточнения систем
    массового участия. Товарищи! рамки и место обучения кадров требуют от нас анализа существенных финансовых и административных условий. Разнообразный и богатый опыт рамки и место обучения кадров влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации направлений
    прогрессивного развития. Задача организации, в особенности же реализация намеченных плановых заданий требуют определения и уточнения систем массового участия. Товарищи! дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности влечет за собой процесс внедрения
    и модернизации дальнейших направлений развития. Таким образом реализация намеченных плановых заданий представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки модели развития. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также рамки и место обучения кадров способствует
    подготовки и реализации дальнейших направлений развития. Товарищи! укрепление и развитие структуры обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании систем массового участия. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что рамки и
    место обучения кадров обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании существенных финансовых и административных условий. Не следует, однако забывать, что постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности представляет собой
    интересный эксперимент проверки форм развития. Повседневная практика показывает, что консультация с широким активом требуют определения и уточнения систем массового участия. Товарищи! рамки и место обучения кадров требуют от нас анализа существенных
    финансовых и административных условий. Разнообразный и богатый опыт рамки и место обучения кадров влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации направлений прогрессивного развития. Задача организации, в особенности же реализация намеченных плановых
    заданий требуют определения и уточнения систем массового участия.</main>
  <aside class="right">...а этот грид-элемент, как следствие должен начинаться сразу после .left</aside>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Для понимания: блоки `.left` и `.right` являются боковыми панельками, которые в определенном брейкпоинте должны сложиться в одну панель слева (в примере media queries убраны, для облегчения понимания). В примере так и происходит, НО! Высота блока `.left` и блока `.right` растягиваются по контенту блока `.main`. Соответственно, при большом кол-ве контента в блоке `.main`, непрерывная панель из `.left` и `.right` уже не получается.
Вопрос: как заставить боковые панели тянуться в высоту по собственному контенту, а не по высоте `.main`?

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Вроде как `auto` ему выставить?

Comment: Qwertiy, было б славно, если б немного конкретнее

Comment: если бы я знал конкретнее, я бы ответ писал, а не комментарий

Comment: @Renton , я так понял вам надо что-то вроде masonry - сетки. На `css-grid` такое вряд-ли  не получится, т.к. чёткое разбиение на ряды. Можно на `flexbox` с дополнительным блоком-обёрткой.

Answer (score 0):

Переписал с `grid-template-areas` на чуть более управляемый синтаксис.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 3fr;
}

.header {
  background: gold;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.left {
  background: silver;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.main {
  background: blue;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 5;
}

.right {
  background: green;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.footer {
  background: red;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <aside class="left">Вот этот грид-элемент должен тянуться (в высоту) по контенту, а не по высоте .main ... </aside>
  <main class="main">Товарищи! дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации дальнейших направлений развития. Таким образом реализация намеченных плановых заданий представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки модели
    развития. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также рамки и место обучения кадров способствует подготовки и реализации дальнейших направлений развития. Товарищи! укрепление и развитие структуры обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие
    в формировании систем массового участия. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что рамки и место обучения кадров обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании существенных финансовых и административных условий. Не следует,
    однако забывать, что постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки форм развития. Повседневная практика показывает, что консультация с широким активом требуют определения и уточнения систем
    массового участия. Товарищи! рамки и место обучения кадров требуют от нас анализа существенных финансовых и административных условий. Разнообразный и богатый опыт рамки и место обучения кадров влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации направлений
    прогрессивного развития. Задача организации, в особенности же реализация намеченных плановых заданий требуют определения и уточнения систем массового участия. Товарищи! дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности влечет за собой процесс внедрения
    и модернизации дальнейших направлений развития. Таким образом реализация намеченных плановых заданий представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки модели развития. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также рамки и место обучения кадров способствует
    подготовки и реализации дальнейших направлений развития. Товарищи! укрепление и развитие структуры обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании систем массового участия. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что рамки и
    место обучения кадров обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании существенных финансовых и административных условий. Не следует, однако забывать, что постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности представляет собой
    интересный эксперимент проверки форм развития. Повседневная практика показывает, что консультация с широким активом требуют определения и уточнения систем массового участия. Товарищи! рамки и место обучения кадров требуют от нас анализа существенных
    финансовых и административных условий. Разнообразный и богатый опыт рамки и место обучения кадров влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации направлений прогрессивного развития. Задача организации, в особенности же реализация намеченных плановых
    заданий требуют определения и уточнения систем массового участия.</main>
  <aside class="right">...а этот грид-элемент, как следствие должен начинаться сразу после .left</aside>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Читайте и изучайте https://gridbyexample.com, там есть ответы на очень большое количество вопросов по построению раскладок с гридами. И не забывайте в девелопер-тулс тыкать в значения и менять их, отслеживая эффект — лучший способ научиться :)